# git and bitbucket cannot delete folder

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a problem with my onine repo.
I have a folder that is not clickable and I have no idea about how to remove it, this folder is no logner avaiable in my repo so I don't need it!

Here what I see:

[image]

That folder was a git repo and some days ago I just copy the cloned folder into a new progect and I think that bitbucket see it as a external repo and not as a regular folder.

By the way now that repo doen't exists anymore and also the fodler in the project has been removed but I cannot remove from online repo and this is a problem for an external deplyo service that I need to use!

Ho can I remove the fodler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here how I solved:

1. `git rm --cached path/to/submodule` whithout the trailing slash
2. then I delete the files: `rm -rf .git/modules/submodule_name`
3. commit the change
4. push it